# Is there cfscript support for looping over a query with the group attribute

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm running the following code in Adobe ColdFusion 10.  I'd like to remove all tags and do this in script.  Real code is more complex, this is just a shell for demo.

Any cfscript support for this?  You should be able to copy and paste this code as is for an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
<h1>Task Migration</h1>
<cfscript>
    id=0;
    commentid=0;
    qryTasks = queryNew("tasknumber,name,commentid,comment"
                        ,"integer,varChar,integer,varChar"
                        ,[ 
                            { 
                                tasknumber : ++id
                                ,name : "Task Name for #id#"
                                ,commentid: ++commentid
                                ,comment : "comment #commentid# on tasknumber #id#"
                            }
                            ,{ 
                                tasknumber : id
                                ,name : "Task Name for #id#"
                                ,commentid: ++commentid
                                ,comment : "comment #commentid# on tasknumber #id#"
                            }
                            ,{ 
                                tasknumber : ++id
                                ,name : "Task Name for #id#"
                            }
                            ,{ 
                                tasknumber : ++id
                                ,name : "Task Name for #id#"
                                ,commentid: ++commentid
                                ,comment : "comment #commentid# on tasknumber #id#"
                            }
                        ] 
                );  
    writedump(var:qryTasks, label:"starting query");
    traceLog=[];
</cfscript>

<cfloop query="qryTasks" group="tasknumber">
        <cfscript>
            arrayAppend(traceLog, "Make a ticket for #qryTasks.name#");
        </cfscript>
        <cfloop group="commentID">
            <cfscript>
                if (trim(qrytasks.comment) != ''){
                    arrayAppend(traceLog, "Add comment to #qryTasks.name#: #qrytasks.comment#");
                };
            </cfscript>
        </cfloop>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#tracelog#" label="Stuff that happened in the loop" />
```

Comment: As far as i remember, `group` is not an available attribute to `for` loops within cfscript. If you're requiring this functionality on a regular basis, create a method which simulates the `group` behaviour.

Comment: Railo actually supports a `loop` command in cfscript with the `group` attribute, Adobe promised to port all functionality from tags to script with CF9 and CF10 but well, Adobe. So go for the old school way `if(current_group_value eq old_group_value) continue;`

Comment: Looks like it is done in CF11

Answer (score 4):

Going with an answer of "Not Possible".  There are workarounds, but I'm not interested in that. RAILO does it and Adobe CF11 does it.  But not doable in ACF10

Comment: And for those looking to do it in railo/cf11/whatever the newest os cfml platform is, the answer is the general way of using a cf tag in cfscript: `cfloop (query="dogs" group="breed") { writeOutput(dogs.breed); cfloop () { writeOutput(dogs.name); }}`

Answer (score -1):

There is the following [example of looping over a query in the Using CFScript statements documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a0e0-7fdf.html#WSe61e35da8d318518-6b2724301353e83f33b-8000). If you define the grouping within your query then it may give you what you need.

> **for-in construct (for query)**
>
> Similar to looping over array and struct, using for-in construct, you can loop over query object in CFScript.
>
> **Example**
>
> In this example, query resultset is available in the variable arts and the for-in loop is used to loop over the resultset. The variable row used in the for-in construct is a struct that contains query columns as keys. You can use arts.currentrow to reference the current row.
>
> ```
> <cfquery name="arts" datasource="cfartgallery"> 
>     select * from art 
> </cfquery> 
> <cfscript> 
>     cols = listToArray(listsort(arts.columnlist, "textnocase")); 
>     for(row in arts) 
>     { 
>         for(col in cols) 
>             writeoutput(arts.currentrow & " ..." & col & ": " & row[col] & "<br>"); 
>         writeoutput("<hr>"); 
>     } 
> </cfscript>
> ```
>
> **Note:** You have to prefix queryname to access the query result variables such as recordcount or currentrow (as shown in the example).

Comment: Not what I'm looking for.  This loops over the columns in the query.  I want the grouping feature that seems to be available in CF11, but probably not CF10. Adam Cameron posted great CFSCRIPT resource at http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/09/documentation-for-cfscript.html

Comment: @GerryGurevich Yeah after I posted this I realized you are asking more about the _group_ attribute of cfloop then looping over the query itself. But your posted example is using tags so wasn't sure if you knew how to loop over the query in cfscript either. I was able to find this example of using a Java HashMap to group data - [Grouping data in ColdFusion Using Hash](http://coldfusionexperts.wordpress.com/2014/03/13/grouping-data-in-coldfusion-using-hash/)